# Access to path **** is denied

Tags: c#

I know there is a ton of stuff on this already and have tried a few things but have had no luck in fixing it.

I have a C# program that has built an XML Document and im trying to save it to a folder thats in MyDocuments. I am getting the folliwing exception when calling the `XMLDoc.Save` function.

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Ash\Documents\ConfigOutput' is denied

I have visual studio running as administrator. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

I have tried saving onto the desktop and into the C:\ folder aswell.

I am using windows 7.

Running the built executable also doesnt seem to work.

Apologies guys it seems I was being stupid. I had indeed not added a filename to the output path. I'll not delete the question incase anyone else gets done by this gotcha! Thanks for all the help/comments.

Comment: Have you tried saving it to the root of C or another folder? It could be an issue with UAC and permissions on users folders - is this on Win7 or Vista?

Comment: Try running the app as admin rather than visual studio.

Comment: what filename are you specifying?

Comment: Is `ConfigOutput` the name of a directory or the filename you want to use? If it's an existing directory, this is the error I get as well. You need to include a filename in your path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- ConfigOutput is a folder
- ConfigOutput is a file that is in use (opened)
- You're not logged in as User 'Ash'

You should not normally have to run as Admin to write to your own Documents folder.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check and get permission to that directory/file your writing.. for that
use `Security namesapce`

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);    
var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, pathToFolder);
permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);

if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
    // do your stuff
}
else
{
    // alternative stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're not specifying a filename and therefore it can't create a file with the same name as an existing directory - so try changing your path to:

C:\Users\Ash\Documents\ConfigOutput\Out.xml

Answer (score 2):

Try run your app as administrator.

If you want to debug your app, start your Visual Studio as administrator also.

To force app start as administrator take a look at this thread:
[How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-sharp-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

P.S. Check if your file is not already opened by another FileStream or etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this makes a difference, but you may want to specify the folder in a relative rather than absolute manner: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` will provide you with the path of the current user's documents. Check if it's different from the one you provide.

If so, you may need to run the app under a different user or administrator as others have pointed out. Obviously one user isn't allowed to just save files into another user's documents folder.

For me when I debug my app from Visual Studio the documents folder is the same as the user I'm currently logged in as and running Visual Studio under.

You could try `<requestedExecutionLevel
level="asInvoker"
uiAccess="true|false"/>` first and progressively move to `highestAvailable` and `requireAdministrator`.

Alternatively, demand the permissions, catch the exception and print it out:

```
try {
        FileIOPermission fileIOPermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, myDocFolderFile);
        fileIOPermission.Demand();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Debug.WriteLine(se.ToString());
    }
```